# Access data from a dictionary within a list within a list from api

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary, nested

```
{
"get": "standings",
"parameters": {
    "league": "12",
    "season": "2019-2020"
},
"errors": [],
"results": 1,
"response": [
    [
        {
            "position": 1,
            "stage": "NBA - Regular Season",
            "group": {
                "name": "Western Conference",
                "points": null
            },
```

I am being returned information from an API that I would like to access in Python. I would like to access the "position" element. I have tried the following code to no avail:

```
"position": response['response'][0]['id'],
```

This seems to give me either a key Error or an Attribute Error. Can anyone give me some help with this?

Comment: The data which you have provided seems not complete. Do you have `id` key in `response` elements ?

Comment: The dataset is too long is the only reason i didnt post it all, there does not seem to be an id key in the response. However this is not my problem as I am just wondering how to access these elements?

Comment: You mean you want to access the value(s) of `"position"` which is `1`?

Answer (score 1):

You should do this instead:

```py
position = response["response"][0][0]["position"]
print(position) # 1
```